# "npm install <github url>" Downloading from NPM instead of GitHub

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, github, npm

So I am trying to install a package from GitHub, but for some reason `npm install` is pulling a different package (which has the same name) from NPM, instead of GitHub.

When I run `npm install git+https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker`, it for some reason installs the package `https://github.com/onefinestay/react-daterange-picker`. This happens even if I manually insert the GitHub package url into my `package.json` dependancies, and then run `npm install`.

I have even tried deleting all my cache, and even deleting `/node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalling via the command `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`.

Any ideas why `npm install` is pulling from NPM instead of GitHub?

Comment: Do you have a package-lock.json? Which version of npm?

Comment: Yes, but I have also tried running `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install` with no success (I assume that deletes `package-lock.json` as well)

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your error. Running that `npm install` command you listed works for me.

Comment: @jrubins have you tried using a ‘<DatePickerRange />’ component? That’s where it stops working for me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you do `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install` *before* trying your command. But this will install everything according to `package.json` and recreate `package-lock.json`. So when you do your modified command it won't work.

I think the best way is to:

1. `rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules`
2. Modify your `package.json` to use the correct git+https link
3. `npm install`

Comment: Thanks, but I actually even tried making a new app via create-react-app (fresh install) - and it still installs the NPM package instead of the GitHub one I specify